# Configuration only on staging environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was told to make a configuration change to a certain parameter in dot net c# code, so that the code would not be pushed into production servers by mistake by somebody on the team. I don't really understand what that means. Tried googling for it,  but I can't seem to find anything related to this.

Can anybody shed light on what I'm supposed to be doing? What exactly does configuration change mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a web.config file. That's where ASP.Net configuration is typically kept. You may find the configuration you are looking for in there.

[See ASP.Net Web configuration guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400235(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I have no clue why I didn't think about web.config files. Thanks  man. Marked this as the right answer. :)

Comment: Excellent - no worries.